# How to implement RabbitMQ DLQ with Spring Cloud Dataflow

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, spring-cloud-dataflow, rabbitmq-exchange

I tried to configure my stream applications (a processor) to auto bind dlq with current params :

```
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.default.consumer.auto-bind-dlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.declareDlx=true
```

But when I deploy it through dataflow, I got the current error in my applications :

`Shutdown Signal: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-dead-letter-exchange' for queue 's2.kotlin-transform.s2' in vhost '/': received none but current is the value 'DLX' of type 'longstr', class-id=50, method-id=10)`

or

`Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-dead-letter-exchange' for queue 's2.http.s2' in vhost '/': received none but current is the value 'DLX' of type 'longstr', class-id=50, method-id=10)`

I've seen  different people who had the same problem but in the other way : `received 'DLX' of type 'longstr' but current is none` just because they are trying to recreate the queue with different parameter for `x-dead-letter-exchange`

Here I've no way to change the none because it's via dataflow and it's dataflow who create the queue just 2seconds before....

I've tried to force the DLX name via : `spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.deadLetterExchange=MYDLX`

but got the same error :
`Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-dead-letter-exchange' for queue 's2.http.s2' in vhost '/': received none but current is the value 'MYDLX' of type 'longstr', class-id=50, method-id=10)`

Someone can help me ? It can be a bug in the rabbit binder ?

Comment: What version of spring-cloud-stream are you using? Have you tried `spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.auto-bind-dlq=true`? I seem to recall there was a problem with applying defaults in older versions.

Comment: Tried with the latest `extra["springCloudVersion"] = "Hoxton.SR10"` and the 2020.0.0